# Replace entries on a file based on another file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

OK, so I have two files:

```
file1.txt

object1 4598 -3.32 0 XxXxXx
object2 5987 -1.98 0 XxXxXx
object3 4529 -3.01 1 AbXxXx
object4 6134 -2.81 0 XxXxXx
object5 5912 -2.12 0 XxXxXx
object6 4529 -3.01 1 TeXxXx
object7 4529 -3.01 1 LoXxXx
object8 6915 -2.64 0 XxXxXx
...
```

and

```
file2.txt

object2 5987 -1.98 1 AnXxXx
object4 6134 -2.81 1 ChXxXx
object8 6915 -2.64 1 SnXxXx
```

For a given object present in both files, the only differences are in columns 4 and 5. I want to update `file1.txt` with the info provided on `file2.txt`. My desired output would then be:

```
object1 4598 -3.32 0 XxXxXx
object2 5987 -1.98 1 AnXxXx
object3 4529 -3.01 1 AbXxXx
object4 6134 -2.81 1 ChXxXx
object5 5912 -2.12 0 XxXxXx
object6 4529 -3.01 1 TeXxXx
object7 4529 -3.01 1 LoXxXx
object8 6915 -2.64 1 SnXxXx
```

I was able to write a solution using a `for` loop in `bash` along with `grep`, by merging both files, `grep`ing object names based on file1, then do a `tail -1` to get the correct line. It is **really** ugly (see below) and the processing takes too long (file1.txt has 4700 lines), but it does give me the desired output.

```
#!/bin/bash

for k in $(awk '{print $1}' file1.txt)
  do
     grep -w $k <(cat file1.txt file2.txt | sort) | tail -1 >> updated_file1.txt
  done
```

Note that I am (dangerously) relying on the fact that `sort` is sorting things based on field 4, since 1-3 are identical. I acknowledge that there is a lot that can go wrong here...

I was wondering if anybody could help me find a faster solution, that for instance would not have to go through the entire file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the first column unique? That is, can it safely be used as a "key" to join the two tables?

Comment: Yes, column 1 is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '      {k=$1 FS $2 FS $3}         # set the key
     NR==FNR {a[k]=$0; next}            # cache the first file's rows by key
     k in a  {$0=a[k]}1' file2 file1    # if key from the second file in cache replace

object1 4598 -3.32 0 XxXxXx
object2 5987 -1.98 1 AnXxXx
object3 4529 -3.01 1 AbXxXx
object4 6134 -2.81 1 ChXxXx
object5 5912 -2.12 0 XxXxXx
object6 4529 -3.01 1 TeXxXx
object7 4529 -3.01 1 LoXxXx
object8 6915 -2.64 1 SnXxXx
```

this assumes first three fields need to match, otherwise change the key to first or first two fields without changing the rest of the code.

Comment: I had no idea that this could be done in awk only. It took me some time to understand the second line of your code, but I think I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: I came up with `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$NF;next} $1 in a{$NF=a[$1]} 1' file2 file1`, which is equivalent but uses a smaller array (both key and value). (Not worth a separate answer.)

Comment: @ghoti, nice and shorter but that will normalize spacing (delimiters), here not relevant but may or may not be desired as a side effect.

Comment: @ghoti, in my specific case both `awk` solutions presented here can be successfully applied, so +1 for presenting an alternative!

Comment: @ghoti, I double checked your solution and actually the output I get only updates the last column. For example, for the last line of the desired output I am getting `object8 6915 -2.64 0 SnXxXx` instead of `object8 6915 -2.64 1 SnXxXx`.

Comment: Ah, you need the last two columns? Then taking the greater memory hit from `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{$0=a[$1]} 1' file2 file1` would be the solution with the least code. Using two arrays, one for $4 and one for $5 would save some memory.  `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$NF;b[$1]=$(NF-1);next} $1 in a{$NF=a[$1];$(NF-1)=b[$1]} 1' file2 file1`

Answer (score 1):

A fun pipeline

```
join -a1 -j1 -o 0,1.2,1.3,2.4,2.5,1.4,1.5 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) |
  tr -s '[:blank:]' |
  cut -d' ' -f 1-5
```

Comment: I should have thought of `join`, but I did not realize it could be done with more than one common field. Thanks for the one-liner!